# Why does the regex \w*(\s+|$) finds 2 matches for "foo" (Java)?

Tags: java, regex

Given the regular expression `\w*(\s+|$)` and the input `"foo"` I would expect that a Java `Matcher.find()` to be true just once: \w* would consume foo, and the `$` in (\s+|**$**) should consume the end of the string.
I can't understand why a second find() would also be true with an emtpy match.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w*(\\s+|$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("foo");

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("'" + m.group() + "'");
    }
}
```

Expected (by me) output:

```
'foo'
```

Actual output:

```
'foo'
''
```

**UPDATE**

My regex example should have been just \w*$ in order to simplify the discussion which produces the exact same behavior.

So the thing seems to be how zero-length matches are handled.
I found the method `Matcher.hitEnd()` which tells you that the last match reached the end of the input, so that you know you don't need another `Matcher.find()`

```
while (!m.hitEnd() && m.find()) {
    System.out.println("'" + m.group() + "'");
}
```

The `!m.hitEnd()` needs to be before the `m.find()` in order not to miss the last word.

Comment: Note that the `(\\s+|$)` isn't necessary - [the same happens without](http://ideone.com/fm9yhI).

Comment: This Java API has always confused me a bit, but isn't the `'foo'` the entire regex match and the `''` the match in parentheses (meaning "the end of the string")?

Comment: @AndyTurner I know it is not needed in this particular case... I tried to dumb down the regex to the bare minimum to expose my case. My real regex is quite complex. I liked your comment in Hollman's question, why print 1 and not 0 (infinity would not be very practical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex can result in a zero-length match, because `\w*` can be zero-length, and `$` is always zero-length.

For full description of zero-length matches, see "[Zero-Length Regex Matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html)" on http://www.regular-expressions.info.

The most relevant part is in the section named "Advancing After a Zero-Length Regex Match":

> If a regex can find zero-length matches at any position in the string, **then it will**. The regex `\d*` matches zero or more digits. If the subject string does not contain any digits, then this regex finds a zero-length match at every position in the string. It finds 4 matches in the string `abc`, one before each of the three letters, and one at the end of the string.

Since your regex first matches the `foo`, it is left at the position after the last `o`, i.e. at the end of the input, so it is done with that round of searching, but that doesn't mean it is done with the overall search.

It just ends the matching for the first iteration of matching, and leaves the search position at the end of the input.

On the next iteration, it can make a zero-length match, **so it will**. Of course, after a zero-length match, is *must* advance, otherwise it'll just stay there forever, and advancing from the last position of the input stops the overall search, which is why there is no third iteration.

To fix the regex, so it doesn't do that, you can use the regex `\w*\s+|\w+$`, which will match:

- Words followed by 1 or more spaces (spaces included in match)
- "Nothing" followed by 1 or more spaces
- A word at the end of the input

Because neither part of the `|` can be an empty match, what you experienced cannot happen. However, using `\w*` means that you will still find matches without any word in it, e.g.

```
He said: "It's done"
```

With that input, the regex will match:

```
"He "
" "       the space after the :
"s "      match after the '
```

Unless that's really what you want, you should just change regex to use `+` instead of `*`, i.e. `\w+(\s+|$)`

Answer (score 4):

The expresion `\\w*` matches zero or more characters, because you are using the [Kleene operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star).

One quick workaround is change the expresion to `\\w+`

**Edit**:

After read the documentation for [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), the find method "starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.". In this case, on the first call all the characters were matched, so the second call starts at empty.

Comment: Well, sure. But surely there are infinitely-many empty strings at the end of the string. So, why print one empty string match, rather than zero or infinity?

Comment: Each position will only match once. On position 0, you find `"foo"`, because of greedy `\w*`. This consumes positions 0, 1 and 2. Then at position 3, you find `""` (0 of `\w` followed by `$`). These are the only positions available, and the regexp engine stops.

Comment: Because it reached the end of the String. On the first run, the RegEx found "foo", then it run again starting right after the last character and found an empty String. Then, once again, it run but after the empty String, and found nothing because it was the end of your data.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 matches, one for the `foo` and one for the foo`here->`.

If the match position changes and it has the
option to match nothing, it will match an extra time.

This only occurs once per match position.
This is to avoid an endless loop of infinite *un-wisedom*.

And, really has nothing to do with the EOS anchor other than it provides
the option to match nothing.

You'd get the same with `\w*` using `foo`, i.e. 2 matches.